# Multiple Submit buttons in django

Tags: django, forms, python-2.7, button, submit

I'm new to Django I need help implementing multiple submit buttons using for loop.
I have a list of elements, which I need to iterate through and create submit buttons (or other type). Pressing one of the buttons, will post the value of the list element and update page.

PS value that is posted and the displayed name should be the same

Example:

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

in views.py

```
from forms import ???
```

in result_page.html

```
{% for el in list1 %}
"code to create buttons"
{% endfor %}
```

The page should display:

one

two

three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views.py you can pass the button names to your template.Use a dictionary and the render_to_response method provided by django.

in the views.py, in your method (one that takes in a "request" object

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
....
context_dict = {list1: list1}  #just passing in the whole list for your for loop in result_page.html
return render_to_response('<directory_to_your_html_file>/result_page.html', context_dict, context)
```

Then in your result_page.html

```
{% for el in list1 %}
<input type="submit" value="{{ el }}"> #double brackets to signify a django variable kinda like {% %}
{% endfor %}
```

Not sure why so many submit buttons, but the same logic applies if you want to use any other input method (eg radio button, checkboxes)

Hope this helps!

edit: Ok from your added comment it seems like you would benefit from something like

```
 <form id="<a form id>" method="<either "POST" or "GET">" action="<directory to the script you are invoking>">
 {% csrf_token %} #don't worry about this one too much, its just django convention
 {% for el in list1 %}
 <input type="radio" name="a_name" value="{{ el }}">{{ el }}<br> #double brackets to signify a django variable   kinda like {% %}
 {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Search"> 
  </form>
```

Try reading on HTML forms http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Thank you! 
This did the trick.
Perhaps, I should use other type of button.
Basically, I need this: 
When I press one of the items from the list1 I then search it in database and return related content on the same page.

Comment: You're welcomed! I added some extra edits to my answer according to the added information in your comment. If it answers the question, would you mind clicking the check mark next to my answer? Thank you and have a good one

Comment: I changed the edit of my answer, check it out, it seems what you really need is just to understand HTML forms correctly and everything will make sense: it's how you will "post the chosen element"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
It looks like I need to use the button type and by pressing one of them, send the value assigned to it(without using submit button).

also I need to keep the same look of the template plus show the new value (guess I need to use session for this)